# Let's get started on the right foot, with the right tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

#### Tags are important

They are used for people trying to find questions, calculating badges, user activity, recommendations for users and suggesting duplicates.

We need to make sure that new tags added are *actually needed* and if they're not, they go, quickly.

#### Tags should be specific but not to specific.

For example, on Ask Ubuntu, there are tags for each version of Ubuntu - [12.04](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/12.04), [14.04](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/14.04) and so on.

However, there are no tags for the point releases - [14.04.2](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/14.04.2) would be pointless.

While this won't apply to us so much, we need to have the same balance of specific tags, with correct synonyms (for example, [apt](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt) and [apt-get](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apt-get) should be synonyms.

[installation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation) is too broad - installing a system and installing software are totally different things, and there needs to be the distinction in the tags. I'd suggest [software-installation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-installation) and [system-installation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) - but then I'm active on Ask Ubuntu, and maybe there is a better alternative.

#### Tag edits are annoying and bump questions

There isn't much that can be done about the first point - yes it's annoying to review them but if they're improving the quality, they're not a bad thing.

Bumping questions to the front page doesn't help though, and the best way to avoid this is to edit when you see the question asked - not 3 weeks later.

#### Meta is the right place

If you want to know if a tag should be changed, if it's too broad or too narrow, if you want your tag wiki / excerpt reviewed, ask here. Make sure to tag it [tags](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) so people can find it, and respond well.

Synonyms can be asked here as well - for the mods to put through quickly. However, the current mods are the SE Community Managers, and so it probably won't be quick.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding versions: I would suggest that code name tags are valid such as [jupiter](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jupiter), [luna](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luna), [freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freya) (though I'm sure nobody here will be using Jupiter).

Comment: And make the 0.1 0.2 0.3 synonyms of that? Also if you use the markup `[tag:luna]` it will look like a tag, like in my post.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a good idea to add numbers as synonyms

Comment: One more point to add, if your question applies to more than one, none should be added.

Comment: I guess that's hard because a user might not know if their question is version specific or not. Should we edit that based on the answer they receive then or?

Comment: Yes, if someone asks about their specific version it should be there. If we later discover it's not version specific (e.g. applies to all new versions, like 13.10 questions do with Ubuntu) then remove the tag :)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't agree more.

Maybe tags for default apps provided by Elementary?

Something like [pantheon-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pantheon-files) or [files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/files), [noise](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise) or [music](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music), [maya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maya), [midori](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midori), [audience](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audience), [plank](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plank) (with [dock](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dock) as a synonym etc.

Comment: I think we should use the names we refer to them as in the UI and set code names as synonyms. So the tag is `[tag:Music]`, and have a synonym `[tag:noise]`

Comment: And the email one?

Comment: While in the future I'd like to refer to Geary as Mail, we still currently call it Geary. I think it would be more familiar for people to use the names they see in elementary OS

Comment: And files should be the main tag, make pantheon a synonym.

Comment: Sure, but is there an admin that can make a basic list of tags for the whole site, or how does it exactly work? How do you make tags synonymous?

Comment: @pawel.ad http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work